# Sequence contains more than one element... in LINQ's DeleteAllOnSubmit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

Following examples are in C#. I am coding for Windows Phone 8.0 using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

I have a simple database design (two primary tables, and one many-to-many linking table)

```
Ingredients(IngredientID,IngredientName)
Effects(EffectID,EffectName)
IngredientEffects(IngredientID,EffectID)
```

so of course to get the foreign keys working I have the standard Entities and Relationships set up in all three tables

This works fine for the following:
- Adding multiple Ingredients
- Adding multiple Effects
- Adding multiple IngredientEffects
- Deleting an Ingredient (and all of it's associated link records)
- Deleting an IngredientEffect record
- Deleting an Effect record... but only if it isn't linked to any Ingredients

When I try to delete an Effect record with multiple Ingredients linked to it, I query for all associated IngredientEffect records then do a DeleteAllOnSubmit(list); SubmitChanges();
This throws multiple "System.InvalidOperationException" with message of "Sequence contains more than one element" is being thrown in the set operation of the Ingredients.FKIngredientEffects Entity Relationship in the IngredientEffects table. I have tried to build a list of UNIQUE records from this list so I know I have no duplicate records in the list being deleted but get the same message.

I understand that this error happens with the Single type queries, but I'm not using any of those. My queries typically run like:

```
var query = from item in db.IngredientEffects 
                    where item.EffectID == targetEffectID 
                    select item;
```

I validate that the query is not null, then attempt to populate a list from it, and check if it is not null and has records in it before proceeding with any other work.

I am at a loss as to why I am getting this error. I use the following Entity Relationship statements in the related Table definintions:

## Ingredients:

```
private EntityRef<IngredientEffect> _ingredientEffect;
[Association(Storage = "_ingredientEffect", ThisKey = "IngredientID", OtherKey = "IngredientID", IsUnique = false, Name = "FK_Ingredients_IngredientEffect")]
public IngredientEffect IngredientEffects
{
    get { return _ingredientEffect.Entity; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            if (value != _ingredientEffect.Entity)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("IngredientEffects");
                _ingredientEffect.Entity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IngredientEffects");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLineIf(Debugger.IsAttached, "AlchemistDB.Ingredients.FKIngredientEffects(set) Exception: " + exc.Message);
            //throw new Exception("AlchemistDB.Ingredient.FKIngredientEffects(set) failed.", exc);
        }
    }
}
```

## Effects:

```
private EntityRef<IngredientEffect> _effectIngredients;
[Association(Storage = "_effectIngredients", ThisKey = "EffectID", OtherKey = "EffectID", IsUnique = false, Name = "FK_Effect_IngredientEffect")]
public IngredientEffect EffectIngredients
{
    get { return _effectIngredients.Entity; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("EffectIngredients");
            _effectIngredients.Entity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EffectIngredients");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLineIf(Debugger.IsAttached, "AlchemistDB.Effect.FKEffectIngredients(set) Exception: " + exc.Message);
            //throw new Exception("AlchemistDB.Effect.FKEffectIngredients(set) failed.", exc);
        }
    }
}
```

## IngredientEffects:

```
private EntityRef<Ingredient> _ingredients;
[Association(Storage = "_ingredients", ThisKey = "IngredientID", OtherKey = "IngredientID", IsUnique = false, IsForeignKey = true, Name = "FK_Ingredients_IngredientEffect")]
public Ingredient Ingredients
{
    get { return this._ingredients.Entity; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            if (value != _ingredients.Entity)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Ingredients");
                this._ingredients.Entity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Ingredients");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLineIf(Debugger.IsAttached, "AlchemistDB.IngredientEffect.FKIngredients(set) exception:" + e.Message);
            throw new Exception("AlchemistDB.IngredientEffect.FKIngredients(set) failed.", e);
        }
    }
}

private EntityRef<Effect> _effects;
[Association(Storage = "_effects", ThisKey = "EffectID", OtherKey = "EffectID", IsUnique = false, IsForeignKey = true, Name = "FK_Effect_IngredientEffect")]
public Effect Effects
{
    get { return this._effects.Entity; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            if (value != _effects.Entity)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Effects");
                this._effects.Entity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Efffects");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLineIf(Debugger.IsAttached, "AlchemistDB.IngredientEffect.FKEffects(set) exception:" + e.Message);
            throw new Exception("AlchemistDB.IngredientEffect.FKEffects(set) failed.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance provided will be most welcome!

Thanks,
-Mark

Answer (score 0):

If any Foreign Key's set declaration in a many-to-many Table has conditional logic (like:

```
if (value!=_myprivateproperty)
{
    NotifyPropertyChanging("MyPublicPropertyName");
    _myprivateproperty = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyPublicPropertyName");
}
```

it will cause LINQ to throw this exception, each time a record in that table is deleted. Get rid of the conditional and just use:

```
NotifyPropertyChanging("MyPublicPropertyName");
_myprivateproperty = value;
NotifyPropertyChanged("MyPublicPropertyName");
```

Still not sure WHY this happens, but to me it appears to be a bug in LINQ-to-SQL itself.